# How to account for CSV parse failure for long flows Ruby/Cucumber

Tags: ruby, csv, parsing, cucumber

Question may not be worded very well.

My issue is this:

Cucumber scenario doing something like this

```
When/^the user reads in company information from (.*)$/ do |input_file| 
   csv_text = File.read(input_file)
   @csv_information = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
end
```

Once that's read in I'm going through long flows filling out forms by doing:

```
@csv_information.each do |row|
  fill in blah with row["foo"]
  fill in blah with row["bar"]
  etc  
  etc
```

My issue/question is:

Say I have 100 rows of a CSV to go through. If I get a failure on row 5, the whole scenario fails/stops.

Is there a way to tell Ruby to start back up on the next line in the CSV after the fail?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the error is occuring in your `@csv_information.each` block because CSV.parse is pretty permissive.

Rescuing the error is the key point.

```
@csv_information.each do |row|
  begin
    fill in blah with row["foo"]
  rescue StandardError => e
    puts "#{e}\n#{e.message}\n#{e.backtrace}"
  end
end
```

If you can, you should rescue a more specific error. You also have some special keywords when iterating:

- `retry` will start over the iteration (i.e. if you're at # 5 it will repeat # 5)
- `next` will go to the next iteration

Comment: <!-- language: lang-rb -->

@csv_information.each do |row|
  begin
    fill in blah with row["foo"]
  rescue StandardError => e
    puts "#{e}\n#{e.message}\n#{e.backtrace}"
    **retry**
  end
end

Comment: Retry is for the rescue. Dont do this unless you're sure your rescue block has corrected the error and it wont be raised again, otherwise you'll get an infinite loop. For loops, you have redo and next. The reason next exists is that returning in a loop won't just skip to the next iteration- it will return from the parent method (if one exists)

Comment: ah okay. for my purposes i'll probably want to just move onto the next iteration.

Comment: simply putting a **next** in the rescue will puts whatever error it came across then move to the next line in the CSV?

Comment: There's no reason to use next as the last statement in an iteration. And it won't print anything.

Comment: are **next** and **retry** part of my rescue? 


"You also have some special keywords when iterating:

retry will start over the iteration (i.e. if you're at # 5 it will repeat # 5)
next will go to the next iteration"

Comment: yeah, i was just giving you a tip for future use. don't use either here.